# Директор Иванова, действующая (действующий)?

Tags: согласование

На  [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/22-spravka/letters/59-rubric-89):

в) определение-причастие ставится в форме женского рода независимо от порядка слов:

Предложившая новую статью автор Н. Петрова уже известна читателям.

Автор Н. Петрова, предложившая новую статью, уже известна читателям.

На той же Грамоте при ответе на Вопрос № 284982

Если генеральным директором является женщина, как правильно построить предложение? В лице генерального директора Ивановой А.Р., действующей / действующего на основании Устава?

пишут:

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Верно: ...в лице генерального директора Ивановой А. Р., действующего на основании Устава.

Так, как же правильно?

Answer (score 5):

1) Причастие согласуется с именем собственным (определяемым словом) в обоих случаях, так как приложение "автор" находится не рядом, а на расстоянии от причастия.

**Предложившая** новую статью автор **Н. Петрова** уже известна читателям.

Автор **Н. Петрова, предложившая** новую статью, уже известна читателям.

2) В лице генерального директора Ивановой А.Р., действующего на основании Устава? 
.. в официально-деловом стиле предпочтительно сохранять форму мужского рода, когда речь идет **о номенклатурном наименовании должности**..." (справочник по правописанию и литературной правке, стр.199)

Answer (score 3):

В приведенном Вами примере возможны оба варианта. Однако в строго деловой речи, когда речь идет именно о ***номенклатурной должности,*** предпочтительно согласование в мужском роде.

Обратите внимание: в первом примере речь не идет о должности.

Answer (score 0):

"Директор Иванова И.И., действующая на основании устава"
Слово "действующая" — это причастие, оно относится к существительному "Директор Иванова И.И.".
Падеж, число, род причастий определяется по падежу, числу, роду существительного, к которому это причастие относится.
В правилах русского языка говорится:
Имена существительные, одушевленные и неодушевленные, некоторые существительные мужского рода, называющие лиц по профессии, должности, роду занятий, обозначают как лиц мужского, так и лиц женского пола: директор Иванов - директор Иванова.
Таким образом, в данном случае *директор Иванова И.И.* — это существительное женского рода.
Поэтому правильный ответ: *директор Иванова И.И., действующая на основании устава.*

Comment: "Директор Иванова И.И" - это существительное? Ильдар, Вам известно определение существительного?

Answer (score -1):

Тут вопрос в том: что является определяемым словом, а что приложением. Если именное — существо, то определяемое слово — именное; в словосочетании «футболист Вася» «Вася» — определяемое слово, а «футболист» — приложение. Если именное — неживое, то определяемое слово — не именное; в словосочетании «журнал Природа» определяемое слово — «журнал», а приложение — «Природа». Это есть в каждом учебнике по синтаксису. Вот первое что нашел. https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/prilozhenie.html Следовательно, слово «действующей» будет относится к «Иванова».