# Род причастия при упоминании женщины «неженской» профессии

Tags: документы

Всегда писали в преамбуле договора ..в лице генерального директора Петровой Э. Т., действующего».. Покупатель исправляет на «действующей». Проверили в Интернете, увидели, что правильно писали. Но Покупатель тоже нашёл вариант правильный, но другой.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ваш вариант можно свести к такому: "директор Петрова действовал (на основании чего-нибудь)" Или у некоего Петрова есть действующий директор?

Comment: Irina19. Вы правы. Много примеров можно найти на [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE). Ранее на нашем форуме уже давали [правильные ответы](https://rus.stackexchange.com/q/419268/183462) на этот же вопрос. К сожалению, сейчас с этим стало похуже.

Answer (score 5):

[Автор Петрова, или Названия «неженских» профессий](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/59-rubric-89)

> ...определение-причастие ставится в форме женского рода независимо от
> порядка слов: *Предложившая новую статью автор Н. Петрова уже известна
> читателям. Автор Н. Петрова, предложившая новую статью, уже известна
> читателям.*

Так что прав покупатель:

*...в лице генерального директора Петровой Э. Т., действующей...*

Answer (score 0):

Тут вопрос в том: что является определяемым словом, а что приложением. Если именное — существо, то определяемое слово — именное; в словосочетании «футболист Вася» «Вася» — определяемое слово, а «футболист» — приложение. Если именное — неживое, то определяемое слово — не именное; в словосочетании «журнал Природа» определяемое слово — «журнал», а приложение — «Природа».
Это есть в каждом учебнике по синтаксису. Вот первое что нашел. https://izamorfix.ru/rus/sint_punkt/prilozhenie.html
Следовательно, слово «действующей» будет относится к «Петрова Э.Т.»

Comment: @grizzly, может быть, вы хоть немного поясните вашу отрицательную оценку моего ответа.

Comment: Причастие, конечно же, будет согласовываться с определяемым словом, а не с приложением. Я дал инструкцию к определению этого определяемого слова и привел доказательства в виде ссылки на статью. Я дал полный, исчерпывающий и безупречный ответ.

Comment: Так, а почему он неправильный?

Comment: Спросите любого юриста, останется ли договор в силе, если госпожа Петрова Э.Т. уволится с должности генерального директора. После этого попытайтесь понять, что говорит Розенталь по поводу официально-делового стиля. Вы должны разобраться самостоятельно, иначе я не смогу Вам помочь. Даже этот комментарий я пишу не для Вас (учитывая ничтожную вероятность того, что он Вам поможет), а для других посетителей.

Comment: То есть это минус из вредности.

Comment: ЛОЛ. Этот человек — школьник, который поставил минус из вредности. Он удалил множество комментариев с каким-то невнятным блеянием, что говорит о том, что самому стыдно. Я не могу оценивать свой ответ — объективно высоким? Может, у вас, в отличии от grizzly, будут аргументы против моего ответа?

Comment: Если бы мне платили по доллару, каждый раз когда вы оскорбляете меня и сливаетесь, то я купил бы новые ботинки.